# VBA Excel Replace last 2 digits of number if occurs at beginning of string

Tags: regex, excel, vba, pattern-matching

I'm trying to replace the last two digits of number with "`XX BLOCK`" if it occurs at the start of the string and has more than 2 digits.

I'm using the *Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5* reference.

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
With regEx
    .Global = True 'Matches whole string, not just first occurrence
    .IgnoreCase = True 'Matches upper or lowercase
    .MultiLine = True 'Checks each line in case cell has multiple lines
    .pattern = "^(\d{2,})" 'Checks beginning of string for at least 2 digits
End With

'cell is set earlier in code not shown, refers to an Excel cell
regEx.replace(cell.Value, "XX BLOCK")
```

Desired results:

```
"1091 foo address"      --> "10XX BLOCK foo address"
"1016 foo 1010 address" --> "10XX BLOCK foo 1010 address"
"foo 1081 address"      --> "foo 1081 address"
"10 bar address"        --> "XX BLOCK bar address"
"8 baz address"         --> "8 baz address"
```

I'm new to regex and not sure where to start. I tried using `^(\d{2,})` but then it replaces the entire number.

There is also a guarantee that the number (if exists) will *always* be followed with a white space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d*)\d{2}\b
```

Or, if you cannot rely on a word boundary, you may also use

```
^(\d*)\d{2}(?!\d) ' no digit is allowed after the 2-digit sequence
^(\d*)\d{2}(?!\S) ' a whitespace boundary
```

And replace with `$1XX BLOCK`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DpHNBx/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d*)` - Group 1: zero or more digits
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\b` - a word boundary, no digit, letter or `_` is allowed right after the two digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Not sure lookaheads are supported in VBScript-flavored regex though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Lookaheads **ARE** supported. Lookbehinds aren't.

Answer (score 2):

*https://regex101.com/r/M1QrPZ/1*

> ```
> Pattern = "^\d{2}(\d{2})"
> ```

*Try the following*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Example()
    Dim RegExp As New RegExp
    Dim Pattern As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Cel As Range

    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1" _
                            ).Range("A1", Range("A9999" _
                            ).End(xlUp))


    Dim Matches As Variant
    For Each Cel In rng
        DoEvents
        Pattern = "^\d{2}(\d{2})"

        If Pattern <> "" Then
            With RegExp
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = Pattern
                 Set Matches = .Execute(Cel.Value)
            End With

            If Matches.Count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print Matches(0) ' full mach
                Debug.Print Matches(0).SubMatches(0) ' sub match
               Cel.Value = Replace(CStr(Cel), Matches(0).SubMatches(0), "XX BLOCK")
            End If
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```